# Typescript: Syntax error. Unexpected token

Tags: typescript, ts-node

I am trying to launch .ts file as console app. 
After converting .ts files to .js (through tsc) there was no error, but I can't launch .ts file with ts-node because of issue:

> "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ..."

My tsconfig.json file is

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterpop": rue
    }
}
```

Typescript code is

```
constructor(... pieces : IPiece[]){
super();
for (let i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    this.add(pieces[i]);
}}
```

So I guess that tsc and ts-node compile .ts files differently. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: ... pieces : IPiece[] ? what is this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `tsconfig.json` file code something spell mistake,

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterpop": rue // here change to true.
    }
}
```

Edit:-

```
... pieces : IPiece[]
```

remove and add `private` or `public` type to this one.

```
constructor(public pieces : IPiece[]){ } //use public or private
```

let try this once and let me know.

Comment: Interpop also sounds a bit fishy

Comment: sorry i cant understand

Comment: Interop , Interoperability

Comment: fixed tsconfig.json. same result

Comment: thanks! that was really helpful!
now it complains "Unexpected reserved word"
typescript code is
import {List} from "typescript-dotnet-es6/System/Collections/List"
any ideas? thanks a lot again!

Comment: please upvote and mark as answer.I will help other thing also

Comment: try this iam not used before but helpful to you,https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-import-list and https://github.com/marcelometal/es6-import-list

Comment: ok thanks also visit this link,https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-dotnet include these also

Comment: Glad to help you.